# Переменная в json объекте

Tags: python, json

```
token = 'fjfakjfasjklfajf'
data = {
"vk_api":token,
"info":"тест"
}
file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

по сути в записанном json файле должно быть такое содержимое:

```
    {
        "vk_api":"fjfakjfasjklfajf",
        "info":"тест"
    }
```

Вместо этого в vk_api он мне записывает такое содержимое:

```
"\u041b\u0451\u043d\u044f"
```

И такое случается, когда в json переменной есть какая-либо переменная

Comment: Это вроде как закодированное слово `тест`

Comment: @E1mir, не, там другое: `>>> "\u041b\u0451\u043d\u044f" 'Лёня'` :D

Comment: Да, то, что я привёл - дубликат слова Лёня. Но дело не в этом.

Comment: Почему он записывает закодированное слово, а не настоящее

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт, в шапке указана ссылка на вопрос, где есть ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт Потому что так легче посылать данные через сеть :) Ну и декодировать его тоже очень просто